# SQL Database Diagram - SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2014, database-diagram, database-diagramming

I typically make a Visio database model diagram, doing a reverse engineer feature.  My issue now is that I have Visio 2010, but I need a model for a database on a 2014 server.  It seems the Visio driver in 2010 is not compatible for SQL Server 2014 database connections.

I tried the generic ODBC connection, but it doesn't show all the fields in each of the tables.

I researched this, and it seems they discontinued reverse engineering SQL databases into models in Visio, after 2013.  I made a SQL diagram, but it's a horrible interface, and I can't get a good visualization of the flow of data, like I can with Visio.

Anyone have any ideas for how I can get a good data model of this database, being that it's on a 2014 server?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54527

Comment: That is for office 365.  Got one for Visio 2016?  I've got that installed, but I can't go any further, right now.

Comment: Good call. I don't have one for Visio 2016. We upgraded to O365 awhile back... good luck on the search. Hope there's a solution here. Seems like a gap in functionality for sure.

Comment: It really is! I just want a nice diagram, that I can move around and show a flow of the data/relationships.  We are on 2010 office, but I can work with 2016, for now.  Upgrading to 365 is not in the near future, so I need to find another way to get this diagram. I feel like I'm flying blind, developing the interface.  I like the diagram to make sure I set up all the interfaces for every part of the data and relationship interactions.